# JQuery sortable making table rows fixed

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table that is sortable via jquery.sortable() function.
Currently, all rows in the table are sortable, with a rownumber stored in a hidden element in that row, and updated whenever the rows are moved.

The problem is that I now have a few tables that require the first half of the rows to be sortable, but the second half to be fixed. Is there any solutions other than to split them into two separate tables?

I have the following HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5px" class="content" id="sort">
  <thead>   
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Created By</td>
        <td>Last Modified By</td>
        <td>Visiblity</td>
        <td>Edit</td>
        <td>Copy</td>
        <td>Delete</td>
        <td>Display Order</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="ui-sortable">
   <tr class="contentbody">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <input type="hidden" class="order" id="order_1" name="order_1" value="1">
   </tr>
   <tr>
     More Content
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I have the following JQuery in a document ready function:

```
/* table sorting */
    var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {
        ui.children().each(function() {
            $(this).width($(this).width());                  
        });
        return ui;
    };
    var sortable = $("#sort tbody").sortable({
        helper: fixHelper,
        stop: function(event, ui) {
         //create an array with the new order
        order = {}
        $(this).find('input.order').map(function(index, obj)
          { 
            return order[this.id] = index;
          }
        );
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: location.href,
            data: order,
            error: function() {
                console.log("Theres an error with AJAX sorting");
            },
            success: function() {
                /* reload table after sort*/ 
            $.get("indexpage_table.php", function(data) { 
                    $("#sort tbody").html(data); 
            }); 
                console.log("Saved.");      
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    });
```

Comment: What is so wrong in splitting the tables? you can split them into two table css them so they still look like one.

Comment: I'd need to move the column headings into php since I'm loading the content dynamically, so anything inside the tbody is referenced after load with the on() function. I think I could modify the sortable function to look something like this: 
`var sortable = $("#sort").on(live(),'tbody',.sortable({ ...`
But I'd really prefer to not have to experiment with that if I don't have to

Answer (score 0):

I added a class to the rows I wanted to be moveable, like so: 
`var sortable = $("#sort tbody .moveable").sortable({ ...`

And I only added the hidden input field and move cursor to the rows that had that class.

It seems to work so far!